# java how to cache objects from two classes and still be able to order them according to their timestamp

Tags: java, algorithm, caching

I have two classes, class1 and class2

both of them has different properties, but both of them has timestamp and transaction id

in the real time, any transactionID will have an instance of class1, and an instance of class2

my current structure to store is to use a hash map for class1, and a hash map for class2 like this:

```
hashmap <transactionID, class1>
hasmap <transactionID, class2>
```

now i got a new requirement which is to cache the instances of both classes, and to have a way to order them according to the timestamp property which they have.

I was thinking and searching about a good approach to do that. i run into `Guava`, but Guava stores objects according to a key, and in my situation, the keys are transactions ids which are not unique.

i want to be able to order (sort) the instances of both classes according to the timestamp properties. i want also to know if there is a data structure that can help be to do that order thing.

I know i can iterate over any strucutre and sore the instances myself, but there should be a better way than this teduis process

Comment: is there any overlap between the transaction ids of class1 and class2 ?

Comment: @AbtPst i don't know what do you mean, but in my case, each transaction id will have an instance of class1 and an instance of class2. Note that the transaction id exists in both of the classes

Comment: can the same transaction id appear for both classes?

Comment: 100% yes, and **each** transaction id will have an instance of each class

Comment: so i guess the combination of transaction id + class is unique. or is it the combination of transaction id + class + timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

Guava's is a good choice it's [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) can hold arbitrary number of elements for the same key value. Using [MultimapBuilder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MultimapBuilder.html) you can create a `MultiMap` that has its keys sorted. Something like:

```
Comparator<TransactionIdType> comparator = // implement Comparator for your TransactionIdType
ListMultimap<TransactionIdType, Object> multimap = MultimapBuilder.treeKeys(comparator).arrayListValues().build();

multimap.put(key1, value1);
multimap.put(key1, value2);
multimap.put(key2, value3);
```

That `MultiMap` will hold two values (value1 and value2) under the same key (key1).

In order to make the implementation better have your value types (class1 and class2 as you call them), implement a common interface in order to have `ListMultimap<TransactionIdType, CommonInteface>` as the `MultiMap`'s parameterization.

*Updated to add caching:*

Guava also offers [caching](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained). Now, this would return all entries in the cache, not sure if that's what you want, perhaps you would start with [getAllPresent](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#getAllPresent(java.lang.Iterable)) and not with [asMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#asMap()).

```
// create cache
final Cache<TransactionIdType, Collection<CommonInterface>> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().build();

// put the value in the cache
Collection<CommonInterface> values = cache.getIfPresent(key1);
if (values == null) {
    values = new ArrayList<CommonInterface>();
}

values.add(type1a);

// get all cached entries, convert them to MultiMap
final Map<TransactionIdType, Collection<CommonInterface>> cacheAsMap = cache.asMap();

final Supplier<Collection<CommonInterface>> supplier = new Supplier<Collection<CommonInterface>>() {
    public Collection<CommonInterface> get() {
        return new ArrayList<CommonInterface>();
    }
};
final Multimap<TransactionIdType, CommonInterface> base = Multimaps.newMultimap(cacheAsMap, supplier);

// sort the MultiMap
ListMultimap<TransactionIdType, CommonInterface> sorted = MultimapBuilder.treeKeys(comparator).arrayListValues().build(base);
```

Comment: the mulitmap link sounds great, but i guess that has nothing to do with each, right? that is a collection utilities offered by google, but not a caching thing, or you mean to cach the multipmap?

Comment: These are indeed two separate things (caching and multimap collection), Guava also offers caching. You can combine both see my updated answer.